# Symbol semi-circ, semi-bullet

Tags: symbols

I would like to create a LaTeX symbol that is mixing both `\circ` and `\bullet`. I want it to be a black circle, the size of `\circ`, with only the lower half filled in black, as on this image.

[image: pokeball]

Do you have ideas about doing this in a not too complicated way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This symbol doesn't seem to be in Unicode.  Somebody (else) can probably tell you how to draw it with tikz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can superimpose a `\circ` to a clipped `\bullet`; here `\ooalign` is our friend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\circbullet}{\mathbin{\vphantom{\circ}\text{\circbullet@}}}
\newcommand{\circbullet@}{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \m@th\ooalign{%
    \clipbox{0 0 0 {\dimexpr\height-\fontdimen22\textfont2}}{$\bullet$}\cr
    $\circ$\cr
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bulletcirc}{\mathbin{\text{\bulletcirc@}}}
\newcommand{\bulletcirc@}{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \m@th\ooalign{%
    \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\clipbox{0 {\fontdimen22\textfont2} 0 0}{$\bullet$}}\cr
    $\circ$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\circbullet b\bulletcirc c$

$\scriptstyle a\circbullet b\bulletcirc c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\circbullet b\bulletcirc c$

\end{document}
```

I also provided the inverse form.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `wasysym` package has `\LEFTcircle`. Note that the capitalization of the command names is important. You can rotate this circle to get a bottom circle. They are a bit bigger than `\circ` and `\bullet` so you can scale them to match the size. They are also on the baseline so you can raise them a bit. Alternatively you can use `wasysym` also for the fully closed and open circles, then they match automatically. This may be a bit more consistent because the lines are a bit thinner in the wasysym circles as compared to `\circ`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
Wasysym circles: \LEFTcircle\ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LEFTcircle} \Circle\ \CIRCLE

Scaled to match circ and bullet: \raisebox{1pt}{\scalebox{0.6}{\LEFTcircle}} \raisebox{1pt}{\scalebox{0.6}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LEFTcircle}}} $\circ\ \bullet$

\def\downcirc{\raisebox{1pt}{\scalebox{0.6}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LEFTcircle}}}}

As command: $\downcirc \circ \bullet$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `fontaewome5` package offers the `\faAdjust` icon that, if rotated by 90 degrees, looks simliar to the image in your question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\faAdjust}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Stix` and `oplotsymbl` package define also the symbols "*semi-circ, semi-bullet*" that you can use also with `\scriptstyle` or with the option `\scriptscriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{oplotsymbl}

\begin{document}
$\circletophalfblack$, $\circlebottomhalfblack$

$\circletfillha$, $\circletfillhb$
\end{document}
```

[image]